# Git submodule error - 'Blink' does not have a commit checked out

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I know this has been asked before, but I've read the previous questions and it didn't solve my problem.

When I run `git submodule add https://github.com/TheOnlyTails/Blink`, an error message appears saying `'Blink' does not have a commit checked out`.

I have checked multiple times for anything that can make this happen. The repository is not empty, and everything should be fine. What's happening?